# Symfony HttpFoundation/File guessing incorrect mime type

Tags: symfony

I have raw png file content and after storing it with `file_put_contents($path, $content)` I'm creating `$file = new File($path);` and when I'm trying to get mine type `$file->getMimeType()` I'm getting **application/octet-stream** instead of **image/png**. Any idea how I can get correct mime type?

Comment: Whats in `$content`? What do you mean by "i have raw png"? Do you generate that? Or what is its origin?

Comment: I'm getting POST request from another service, and that service using file_get_contents to get the contend and passing it to request body.

Comment: Can you check the original file in you cli with `file --mime-type`? Does it start with the right png signature? See http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Rationale.html#R.PNG-file-signature

Comment: Can't check it right now, but when I'm doing file_get_contents($file); $file = new File($file); $file->getMimeType(); on that service where Im creating request I see correct image/png mine type... So I think file is correct and issue is in sending through http, but I can't figure out what is wrong...

Comment: Symfony comes with an array of MimeTypeGuessers (https://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/MimeType.html). You should start debugging there. Which guesser detects the `image/png` before you create the request? That might give you a hint, why it fails afterwards.

Comment: In both cases `FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser` guessing mime type but on the sender side it's image/png and on receiver, it's application/octet-stream...

Comment: hmm,when I'm doing `file --mime-type` on the sender side I I see the error like `/var/www/project# /var/www/project/15422810201547721357.png   --mime-type
/var/www/project/15422810201547721357.png: line 1: �PNG
/var/www/project/15422810201547721357.png: line 2: : not found
/var/www/project/15422810201547721357.png: line 2: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")

`

and on receiver `/var/www/project/201547721357.png   --mime-type
/var/www/project/15422810201547721357.png: line 2: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")`

Comment: but on sender side I can open and see the image and on reciever not

Comment: I tried several images and same issue...